# how to dispaly image in grid view reading imageUrl from xml using sax parser in android

Tags: android, parsing, sax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to display image in grid view reading imageUrl from xml using sax parser in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6530659/how-to-display-image-in-grid-view-reading-imageurl-from-xml-using-sax-parser-in-a)

thanks for answer but i am able to read xml file from url but i need if in xml imageUrl is there so show in grid view ..this is my xml file and read URL

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<channels>
    <channel>
        <name>ndtv</name>
<logo>http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/670625317/aam-logo--twitter.png</logo>     
        <description>this is a news Channel</description>
        <rssfeed>ndtv.com</rssfeed>
    </channel>
    <channel>
        <name>star news</name>
<logo>http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/740897825/AndroidCast-350_normal.png</logo>        
        <description>this is a newsChannel</description>
        <rssfeed>starnews.com</rssfeed>
    </channel>
</channels>
```

Comment: I really don't understand your question.

Comment: this is my Xml file store some place i want to read this xml file and show the imageurl  iamge in gridview using SAX parser.  thanks

Comment: @PramodKumar did u achieved displaying xml images in gridview?

Answer (score 0):

There is a tutorial on SAX parsing [here](http://www.jondev.net/articles/Android_XML_SAX_Parser_Example), an example of HttpClient [here](http://w3mentor.com/learn/java/android-development/android-http-services/example-of-http-get-request-using-httpclient-in-android/), and a tutorial on GridView [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html).

You'll need to parse your XML, store your URLs in a list, retrieve those URLs using HttpClient, load the images in to Bitmap objects, and set your ImageView objects in your `getView()` method of your `Adapter` using `imageView.setImageBitmap()`.

Sorry for the very broad answer, but it's a very broad question.